# Pandas Dataframe: Removing redundant rows in headers

Tags: python, pandas

```
                 daysago  line_race rating  rw    wrating
 line_date                                                 
 2007-03-31       62         11     56  1.000000  56.000000
 2007-03-10       83         11     67  1.000000  67.000000
 2007-02-10      111          9     66  1.000000  66.000000S
```

I was doing an analysis on pandas.dataframe, and i ended up with a dataframe, df, as shown above.

I want to display both line_date and rating. I wanted to do a `df['line_date','rating']` but i can't because line_date is technically on the second row.

How do i push line_date to be on the first header row like the rest?

My ideal output:

```
 line_date        daysago  line_race rating  rw    wrating                                               
 2007-03-31       62         11     56  1.000000  56.000000
 2007-03-10       83         11     67  1.000000  67.000000
 2007-02-10      111          9     66  1.000000  66.000000S
```

Intuitively, I would remove line 2 such that the data flushes to the top just below the headers, and then I will change the name for col 0. 
Is there a better way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not really two lines. The `'line_date'` on the "second line" in the left column is actually the name of the column that was made the index.

Just try `df.reset_index()` (assuming your DataFrame is `df`); `df.reset_index(inplace=True)` will do modify it in place (as the parameter implies).